# $x^3=a+1,x+{b\over x}=a,x=?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$x^3=a+1,x+{b\over x}=a,x=?$

I did in usual manner of finding root of quadratic equation, but got roots with surd factors, but here are the options

a) $a(b+1)/(a^2-b)$

b) $(ab+1)/(a^2-b)$

c) $(ab+a+1)/(a^2-b)$

d) $(ab-a-1)/(a^2-b)$

Thank you

Comment: the stupidest exersice I've ever seen

Comment: I've seen worse than this one...and I also couldn't do it directly. :) For @miosaki: check every option and substitute in the given equations. Either there's some slick trick hidden there or you're expected to solve very nasty algebraic . equations. Anyway it is too much work, the kind of one that makes many high-school kids hate mathematics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x+\frac{b}{x}=a=>x^2=ax-b=>x^3=ax^2-bx=>a+1=ax^2-bx=>ax^2=bx+a+1=>a(ax-b)=bx+a+1=>a^2x-bx=ab+a+1=>x=\frac{ab+a+1}{a^2-b},a^2-b\neq0$